# Swift UITableView - How to put new items on top not on the bottom of the list?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in Swift. The sample codes about UITableView show that new item is placed on the bottom of the list. How may we reverse this? I searched internet but could not find an answer.

Thanks.
Guven

Comment: add item to the array last index . then reload tableView

Comment: Top or Bottom?? @VineeshTP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UITableviews show data based on the order of an array such as an array of characters like

```
var data = ["B","C","D","E"]
```

Typically, you add data into array by using append which adds data at the end of the array, hence why it adds it at the bottom of the list.

```
data.append("A")
```

If you want your table view to add data on top of the list, then you can add your data at the beginning of the array like this.

```
data.insert("A", at: 0)
```

now reload your tableView, and new data would be added at the top of the list

```
yourTableViewName.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 4):

To put new item on top, insert it at desired position (index 0) and reload corresponding indexPath (row: 0, section: 0).

```
let indexPathOfFirstRow = NSIndexPath.init(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
yourArray.insert("some element", atIndex: 0)

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathOfFirstRow], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Reloading whole table is a costly task and not recommended.

Comment: Why would you use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`? Simply using `inserRowAtIndexPaths` would work just as well?

Comment: I would say that it is highly recommended to update your set of data outside the beginUpdates

Answer (score 0):

Add item to the array last index .
Then reload tableView

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is to .insert your object at index 0 rather than append. Appending your latest value at the first index 0 ensures your last data is shown at the top.[image] You can continue using tableview.reloaddata()as usual. Hope the screenshot helps

Comment: Please don't post code, data, error messages as pictures. Post the code directly here on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting new items on data array at 0 index is easy but keeping the state of tableview as it is difficult especially when you are dealing with headers too...

I am using this to append old messages when paginating the chat...

you can iterate on data and insert new items and header with `data.insert("new message", at: 0)`  but tableview automatically going to jump on zero index. to keep that state you should need a unique id in every new item in my case it was `time` and `messageId`

I am saving the last message id before appending new items ... and using that id to calculate the indexPath of the previous top message cell and scroll to it with no animation...

```
   func getIndexPath(WithMessageId id: Double) -> IndexPath? {
        for (section, sectionObjects) in messagesArray.enumerated() {
            if let index = sectionObjects.Messages?.firstIndex(where: { $0.MessageID == id }) {
                return IndexPath(row: index, section: section)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

this method returns the indexpath use that as follows

```
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: getIndexPath(WithMessageId: lastMessageID) ?? IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
                                   at: .top, animated: false)
```

its gonna append new items without even any glitches like Twitter appending new news feeds on top...